# Return result and raise exception alternative solution

Tags: python, exception

If there is no possibility to return a result and raise an exception how should I solve something like this:

```py
def get_person():
    person = {}
    person['name'] = get_name()
    # e.g. get_age() can cause an error
    person['age'] = get_age()
    return person
```

Normally when I can't obtain age I would get error. That's good I want that. But in one case I want to get at least the name. And suppose we can't call `get_name()` outside that method.

```py
try:
    # person will not be even declared
    person = get_person()
except ValueException as e:
    if str(e) == 'cannot obtain age':
        person['age'] = None
    else:
        raise e
...
funny_method(person)
```

I am out of ideas. Returning through parameters is unclear. This just suppress the exception:

```py
def get_person():
    person = {}
    person['name'] = get_name()
    try:
        person['age'] = get_age()
    finally:
        return person
```

Return `None` for age property when error occurred seems like the only option, but it would change previous purpose.

Comment: It might be a better design to do the try/catch inside `get_name()` and `get_age()`, and return None in case of error.

Comment: @JohnGordon: then there will never be an exception, but OP wants an exception

Comment: What is the desired behaviour *for the caller*? Should it have to ``try: except:`` for the no-age case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to both `return` a value *and* `raise` an exception. However, it is possible for the exception to carry the value:

```
class IncompletePerson(LookupError):
      def __init__(self, person):
          super().__init__(f"{person!r} information is incomplete")
          self.person = person
```

When the `person` cannot be fully built, pass the partial `person` to this exception and raise it:

```
def get_person():
    person = {}
    try:
        person['name'] = get_name()
        person['age'] = get_age()
    except ValueError:
        raise IncompletePerson(person)
    else:
        return person
```

The caller either receives the complete `person`, or can recover an incomplete `person` if desired:

```
try:
    person = get_person()
except IncompletePerson as ip:
    print(f"Only retrieved: {ip.person!r}")
else:
    print(f"Fully retrieved: {person!r}")
```

Answer (score -1):

> I would get error. That's good I want that. But in one case I want to get at least the name.

If you want two different things, implement two different methods. Call the method that is appropriate to what you want to achieve in the particular case.

Answer (score -1):

What you need is a combination of both of your snippets.

```
def get_person():
    person = {}
    person['name'] = get_name()
    
    try:
        person['age'] = get_age()
    except ValueException as e:
        if str(e) == 'cannot obtain age':
            person['age'] = None
        else:
            raise e
    finally:
        return person
```

Comment: In case of  `raise e` there is no return value